# How do I add an a'href' tag to some text using Nokogiri, given I want HTML output?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have tried many permutations of this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
    doc.html {
        doc.body {
            links.each do |i|
                doc.p {
                    doc.text "#{i.text}"
                } 
                    doc.a["href"] = i[:href]
            end
            }           
        }
end
```

Where `links` is an array that has the values needed for both `test` and `:href`.

What this produces is (abbreviated for brevity):

```
This is the HTML generated
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>10 &#8729; Progamer Lim Yohwan, the E-Sports Icon</p>
<a href="http://boxerbiography.blogspot.com/2006/12/10-progamer-lim-yohwan-e-sports-icon.html"></a>
```

Where what I want it to produce is:

```
<p><a href="http://boxerbiography.blogspot.com/2006/12/10-progamer-lim-yohwan-e-sports-icon.html">10 &#8729; Progamer Lim Yohwan, the E-Sports Icon</a></p>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [builder interface](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Builder.html), attributes are supplied as arguments to the `doc.tagname` call and the content goes inside the block. So something like this should do the trick:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
    doc.html { 
        doc.body { 
            links.each do |i| 
                doc.p {
                    doc.a(:href => i[:href]) {
                        doc.text i.text # or maybe i[:text]
                    }
                }
            end  
        }    
    }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

mu is correct, but isn't it nicer like this?

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
    doc.html do |html|
        html.body do |body|
            links.each do |i|
                body.p do |p|
                    p.a i.text, :href => i[:href]
                end 
            end
        end
    end
end
```